# Python Replacing every imaginary value in array by random

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers, replaceall

I got an

```
array([[ 0.01454911+0.j,  0.01392502+0.00095922j,
         0.00343284+0.00036535j, 0.00094982+0.0019255j ,
         0.00204887+0.0039264j , 0.00112154+0.00133549j,  0.00060697+0.j],
       [ 0.02179418+0.j,  0.01010125-0.00062646j,
         0.00086327+0.00495717j, 0.00204473-0.00584213j,
         0.00159394-0.00678094j, 0.00121372-0.0043044j , 0.00040639+0.j]])
```

I need a solution which gives me the possibility to replace just the imaginary components by an random value generated by:

```
numpy.random.vonmises(mu, kappa, size=size)
```

The resulting array needs to be in the same form as the first one.

Comment: With `size` being the size of the original array? In this case maybe `numpy.real(a) + numpy.random.vonmises(mu, kappa, size=size) * complex(0, 1))`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your solution approach gave me a good idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach:

- Store your numbers into a 2-D array: Real-part and Imaginary-part.
- Then replace the Imaginary-part with the randomly chosen numbers.

Comment: I thought about this solution too, but my array mustn't be changed. I need it for later calculations in the same form

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the numbers and just set them to a value you like. The parameters `mu` and `kappa` for the `numpy.random.vonmises` function need to be defined, since in they are undefined in the below example.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[ 0.01454911+0.j,  0.01392502+0.00095922j,
         0.00343284+0.00036535j, 0.00094982+0.0019255j ,
         0.00204887+0.0039264j , 0.00112154+0.00133549j,  0.00060697+0.j],
       [ 0.02179418+0.j,  0.01010125-0.00062646j,
         0.00086327+0.00495717j, 0.00204473-0.00584213j,
         0.00159394-0.00678094j, 0.00121372-0.0043044j , 0.00040639+0.j]])

def setRandomImag(c):
    c.imag = np.random.vonmises(mu, kappa, size=size)
    return c

data = [ setRandomImag(i) for i in data]
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't write the code correctly, because it doesn't work.

Comment: If I replace the assignment of the random value by a fixed value, such as ``10``, it works fine. I specifically wrote, that the parameters of the ``random.vonmises`` need to be defined somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
n_epochs = 2
n_freqs = 7
# form giving parameters for the array

data2 = np.zeros((n_epochs, n_freqs), dtype=complex)
for i in range(0,n_epochs):
     data2[i] = np.real(data[i]) + np.random.vonmises(mu, kappa) * complex(0,1)
```

It gives my whole `n_epoch` the same imaginary value. Not exactly what I was asking for, but solves my problem.